# How to extend Ansible's setup module to gather more information?

Tags: ansible, solaris

On Solaris Ansible's `setup` module does not gather information about installed zones. How to extend the `setup` module to gather the output of `zoneadm list -iv`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. create a script named `/etc/ansible/facts.d/zoneadm.fact` and gather whatever information you need there. This can be whatever you want (bash/python/etc).
2. When you are done, `echo` it to stdout as json format.
3. Deploy that script via ansible, make it executable
4. Gather facts and notice that the new facts are present under `ansible_local.zoneadm`

More infos can be found [here](http://serverascode.com/2015/01/27/ansible-custom-facts.html)

Comment: What do you mean by `static` ? that script is run everytime you perform the setup step, i.e. `ansible all -m setup`.

Comment: Maybe I miss understood it. Will this script be executed on the target host or on the Ansible host?

Comment: They will be run on the machine on which they're located, which is why @user2599522 was suggesting that you first deploy the facts script to all your hosts.  More on that [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#local-facts-facts-d).

Comment: @XiongChiamiov Thanks! I misunderstood that I have to deploy the fact scripts myself to the target system. I thought Ansible transfers everything necessary on its own and that it is not necessary to deploy anything (agentless). Now things start making sense. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I was dealing with the same dilemma ~2y ago. Previous reply is correct, but you have to deploy some stuff before and the rerun Ansible to get new facts too.

There's an option to write your own Ansible module, which returns `JSON` looking like:

```json
{
  'changed': false,
  'ansible_facts': {
     'sunos': {
       'zonename': 'global',
       'zones': {},
  }
}
```

Facts returned by such module are then merged to ones coming from `setup` module. To be more portable, best to include such module into Ansible role and include just one task calling this module, plus add tag `always`, to get this fact collection run even when you choose subset of tasks by specifying tags on cmdline.

I've got my old role [pushed here on GitHub](https://github.com/nudzo/sunos_facts). Probably will not work out-of-the-box... was used with Ansible 1.0, but get inspired.

Comment: Your solution is somehow different. Instead of collecting the data with a facts script you wrote a module bypassing the facts collection process. Any additional `setup-sunos` module has to be used explicitly whenever `setup` runs automatically. How did you achieve this?

Comment: You miss the point, it is not bypassing anything. The same way `setup` module works. Try `ansible -vvv your_host -m setup` and you'll see very similar `JSON`. Anytime some module returns `ansible_facts`, it is getting merged not overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for my misunderstanding was, that I thought, I have to put something on the Ansible machine, which gets automatically deployed to the target system as it is done with the modules. But facts gathering works differently! One has to take cake, that the fatcs gathering scripts are already on the target system, before the `setup` starts working. I would say this is a design error in Ansible or at least a still not implemented feature.

To add this missing functionality, it is necessary to write a play, which works before all other things. I came up with the following solution:

```
---
- name: facts deployment
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: all
  become: true
  tasks:
    - set_fact: setup_necessary=false
    - file:
        path: "/etc/ansible/facts.d"
        state: directory
        recurse: yes
      register: facts_directory
    - set_fact: setup_necessary=true
      when: facts_directory.changed

- name: solaris facts
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: solaris
  become: true
  tasks:
    - include: deploy_fact.yml
      with_items:
        - { shell: bash, file: nonglobal_zones }
        - { shell: bash, file: solaris_eeprom }

- name: setup after facts update
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - setup:
      when: setup_necessary
```

The above playbook does all plays with `gather_facts: false`, to prevent any `setup` run before the facts have been deployed. All plays set the variable `setup_necessary`, when any change to the target system has been made. It is not possible to use a handler for this, because handlers run at the end of a play, but not at the end of a playbook or after some plays (Ansible limitation 1).

First the directory gets created and after that all facts files are deployed. It is necessary to put the body of the look into a separate task file, because it is not possible to group two tasks together in a playbook (Ansible limitation 2).

The contents of the `deploy_fact.yml` file uses the `template` module to transfer the facts scripts to the target system.

```
---
- name: "/etc/ansible/facts.d/{{item.file}}.fact"
  template:
    src: "{{inventory_dir}}/facts.d/{{item.shell}}.j2"
    dest: "/etc/ansible/facts.d/{{item.file}}.fact"
    mode: 0755
  register: facts_file
- set_fact: setup_necessary=true
  when: facts_file.changed
```

The reason why I use the `template` module is, that every facts script needs some kind of error handling which takes care that proper JSON gets created in case of an error.  This is my current error handling but it can be still improved. Some people also don't like `set -eu`, which is somehow a matter of taste.

```
#! /bin/bash
{% include item.file + '.bash' %}


set -eu

_stderr=$(mktemp)
trap 'rm -f "$_stderr"' EXIT
if _stdout=$(main 2>$_stderr); then
  if [ "$_stdout" ]; then
    echo "$_stdout"
  else
    echo null
  fi
else
  jq -Rsc "{\"ERROR\":{\"failed\":true,\"exit\":$?,\"msg\":.}}" $_stderr
fi
```

The template does nothing more than just including the file passed by the loop via the implicit `item` variable.  The wrapper expects from the included file, that a `main` functions gets defined. This is my main function for non-global zones:

```
main ()
{
  zoneadm list -i |
  grep -v global |
  jq -Rc . |
  jq -sc .
}
```

And this one collects the Solaris eeprom data:

```
main ()
{
  eeprom |
  sed 's/^\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)$/{"\1":"\2"}/' |
  sed 's/^\(.*\): data not available.$/{"\1":null}/' |
  sed 's/:"false"}$/:false}/g' |
  sed 's/:"true"}$/:true}/g' |
  sed 's/:"\([0-9][0-9]*\)"}$/:\1}/' |
  sed '/^{"boot-device"/{s/":"/":["/;s/ /","/g;s/"}$/"]}/;}' |
  jq -sc add
}
```

My bottom line is that it is somehow possible to extend Ansible's facts gathering but it is far from obvious and it is a bit painful, because it makes any ad hoc usage of the `setup` module impossible. Instead of requiring the user to implement the above stuff, Ansible should move all of the above into the `setup` module (Ansible limitation 3).